# Android open source code comparison of android 12 and android 13

Tags: android

Since Google has pushed the Android 13 source to the Android open source project and officially released the newest version of android.
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/08/android-13-is-in-aosp.html

I would like to know where and how we can see the difference between android 12 source and android 13 source codes. I just wanted to know how many apis, class files has been changed.

Please support if any link or information available.

Comment: I'd probably start at https://cs.android.com/

Comment: yes @MartinMarconcini - I am using this - https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject   Are you suggesting to download the andorid 12 and 13 source code and compare with tools?(eg-vim, notepad++ or winmerge)

Comment: Well.. that'd be a bit crazy but possible. Can't you clone the entire ASOP repo and use git to find the diff?